# How to filter images?

Tags: django

The truncatechars and safe filters work the way I want the problem is the image shows up too in my descriptions and I don't want images to show up like they do in this image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoFLB.png

```
{% for post in post_entries %}
<div class="post-preview">
<h3 class="post-subtitle">{{ post.post_text|truncatechars:125|safe }}</h3>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
<h3 class="post-subtitle"><p><img alt="" src="./Journal_files/1555448282201.jpg" style="float:right; height:155px; width:55px">"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrup…</p></h3>
        </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the `<img>` tags (and possibly quite a few others) from your `post.post_text` before rendering it. FWIW, applying the `truncatechars` and `safe` filters in succession to an HTML snippet is a very bad idea, as you can (and *will*) end up with unclosed tags, breaking your own template's markup.

Django provides a `striptags` filter too, but [the offical recommandation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) is to [use `bleach`](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html):

> Note that striptags doesn’t give any guarantee about its output being
>   HTML safe, particularly with non valid HTML input. So NEVER apply the
>   safe filter to a striptags output. If you are looking for something
>   more robust, you can use the bleach Python library, notably its clean
>   method.